Find most frequent value of all the other parameter regarding parameter1 = x and parameter2 = y
I have a GMP table, let's say there are 1000 rows present in the table and 20 columns present as a parameter, lets say 20 row present where parameter1  = x and parameter2 = y and all the other parameter have values also in all the 20 row , what i want a single row where parameter1 = x and parameter2 = y, and the most frequent value of all the other parameters , like param3, param4...param20 where parameter1 is x and parameter2 is y
I want a single row where parameter1 is x  and parameter2 is y

What DB are you using and could you please provide some example data and expected result.

Also show us your current query attempt.

Counting the frequency of values in a group of columns of same type per row requires first an UNPIVOT operation to allow COUNT() in a subselect and then a MAX() on that COUNT() in the upper query., but is that really what you are looking for?
